# Passing text file to standard input

Tags: c++

The following code is part of a larger translator program. The code below asks the user to type a line and than just writes it back. Is there a way that instead of writing a single line each time, I can just pass in a whole file etc 'translate.txt' in standard input and the program can write it back line by line and produces an error when the end of line is reached ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


using namespace std;


void PL() {

    char line[BUFSIZ];

    while( cin.good() ) {
         cout<<"Type line now"<<endl;
         cout<<"\n";
         cin.getline(line, sizeof(line));
         cout<<"\n"<<endl;
         string mystring = string(line);

        // supposed to Parsing string into words and translate// 
        //but just reading back input for now//

        cout<<"You typed:"<<mystring<<endl;
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    }

}

int main() {
    PL();
}
```

Comment: Yes but it is external to C++. It is down to the shell the program is run in. In Linux BASH you can pipe data and cat files. So if I want to send `myfile.txt` to the standard input of `myprog` I would run it like this: `cat myfile.txt | myprog`. Note the pipe symbol is `|` and it pipes the file to the standard input.

Comment: Yes I am supposed to run this on SSH shell, you execute the program by writing: ./cat
writing ./cat example.txt does not work, even though example.txt was in the same dir as the prog in secure shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you expect a way to pass a file to your program?

```
executable < file
```

Comment: Yes but not sure how to do so

Comment: got it, if you are running this in ssh secure shell, you need to make an executable and type this:


./runthis <myfile.txt

where runthis is the name of your executable and myfile is the text file you are passing. Both should be in the same dir on your ssh drive

Comment: @slk Note, that there are several ways to provide input files for your program. The most flexible option is, to use command line arguments passed to your program directly.

Answer (score 1):

[This code works well for me](http://ideone.com/XN91DP):

```
void PL() {
   string line;

    while(cin) {
        cout<<"Type line now";
        if(std::getline(cin,line)) {
            // supposed to Parsing string into words and translate// 
            //but just reading back input for now//
            cout<<"You typed:"<<line<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `stdin` there is actually passed to the program from the shell as mentioned:

```
$ executable < file
```

---

If you want to pass arbitrary types of streams created from outside this function, you'll need something like

```
void PL(std::istream& is) {
   string line;

    while(is) {
        cout<<"Type line now";
        if(std::getline(is,line)) {
            // supposed to Parsing string into words and translate// 
            //but just reading back input for now//
            cout<<"You typed:"<<line<<endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream is("mytext.txt"); // hardcoded filename
    PL(is);
    return 0;
}
```

or alternatively

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::istream* input = &std::cin; // input is stdin by default
    if(argc > 1) {
        // A file name was give as argument, 
        // choose the file to read from
        input = new std::ifstream(argv[1]);
    }

    PL(*input);

    if(argc > 1) {
        // Clean up the allocated input instance
        delete input;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<sub>There are certainly more elegant solutions</sub>

and calling from the command line:

```
$ executable mytext.txt
```

Comment: I see you made it more straight forward, thanks !
Now how do i pass it a text file instead in ssh secure shell

Comment: @slk Did you check the online sample link, and the inputs I used?

Comment: @slk Do you mean to pass a `std::istream&` parameter to this function, instead of reading from `std::cin` and opening a text file using a `std::ifstream` outside from that function?

Comment: I did, it types back any line i write which is ok but i want to send in a text file instead of writing a single line everytime. I don't exactly remember how my professor did it on the ssh shell but  after it asks you to time in a line, he wrote the address of the file instead..so it means i have to pass in a whole file instead of individual lines

Comment: Just to be clear, what you are saying is that the first code should be to accept files passed into the executable in the linux shell.

Comment: It worked, thanks ! i didn't understand that the comment above literally meant writing "./runthis <myfile.txt " 
where runthis is the executable and myfile.txt is your file

Comment: @slk _"Just to be clear, what you are saying is ..."_ Yup, exactly! The second example is meant how to open files programatically. Another option for the second one, is that the file name is given as an argument to the executable (like `executable file`), and you refer to it via `argv[1]` that was passed to `main()`.

Comment: No, passing command line argument wouldn't work because i am already using that to select what kind of translation to do i.e from piglatin or to piglatin..i am having some problems with making both of these work together though,which is gonna be next question

Comment: @slk I've offered and explained all of the options you currently can choose from.

Comment: @slk _"i am having some problems with making both of these work together though,which is gonna be next question "_ I've found the [`boost program options`  library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html) quite useful, to solve these problems you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell will have a way to pass a file in over stdin. So for example, if you are on a bourne-compatible shell you can run

```
translate < translate.txt
```

(assuming your program is compiled to a binary named `translate`). This is assuming you want to start the program interactively, i.e. from a shell.

If you want to automatically spawn this program from another program you wrote, it depends on your OS. On POSIX operating systems, for example, you will want to `open` the file and `dup2` the resulting file descriptor into `STDIN_FILENO` after forking but before calling one of the `exec` family functions.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know you could just send in your text files into executable like that in the shell.