# Fill in commandLine by passing a file to the scanner

Tags: java, file, input, command-line-interface, java.util.scanner

I am working on a game for school that recuires a lot of input in the commandline. I am now working on the last part. Everytime I want to check if my code works, I need to fill in 20 inputs in the commandline. This can take a lot of time.

In school my teacher told me there is a way to do this by using the scanner and a txt file. But he didn't tell me how to do this..

The idea is this:

In the commandline I wil get prompted to fill in this:

```
Number 1: ...
Number 2: ...
```

In the file I wil put what needs to be filled in (for example):

```
5
10
```

For the scanner I want to do something like this:

```
File file = new File("example.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

So everytime I run the program the scanner wil automaticly fill in the input and I don't need to waste my time doing this.

If there is a more simple way to do this, please let me know, (I am using netbeans btw).

Comment: Run the application from command line, and redirect the file to it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic how do I do this?

Comment: Something like ```$ java -jar application.jar < example.txt```
Check also [passing text file to standard input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985639/passing-text-file-to-standard-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you were using Scanner to get input from the console and now you want to get the input from a file, try this code

```
File file = new File("example.txt");
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        // Do whatever you were doing with the input
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use the full path to the file when you are initializing the file. For example

> C:/working_dir/example.txt